# Correlation between malloc_stats and /proc/pid/stat

Tags: linux, memory-leaks, embedded, malloc

I am working on a embedded linux system. I understand what info [malloc_stats](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_stats.3.html) and [/proc/pid/stats](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html) provide. I want to know how the info printed by malloc_stats is related to the memory usage info provided by /proc/stats.
Background is that I want to instrument each thread in my app to check for memory leaks.Malloc_stats prints useful info but cant be used programatically./proc//task/ has useful info but I am unable to correlate it to the heap memory used by the current thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you overlooked the [`mallinfo()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallinfo.3.html) library function? It's where `malloc_stats()` gets its information from.

To answer the question directly: The data in `/proc` will reflect the total memory usage of the process, including slack space between memory allocations and free memory, as well as memory that's being used which wasn't allocated through `malloc()` at all (e.g, the stack, global/static variables, etc). `malloc_stats()` will break that down into what's actually allocated and what isn't.

Comment: Thank you. My main intention is to get info on per thread basis.I understand best way to get thread wise breakup is to use /proc/pid/task/tid/stat.However based on your reply I understand info on resident set size (rss) does not reflect actual amount of dynamic memory alloced by the thread and total alloted size .Is my understanding correct

Comment: Memory is not tracked on a per-thread basis. It belongs to the process, not just to one thread.

Comment: By definition of a thread, it does not have its own memory space, but shares the memory space with all the threads of the same process. So speaking of memory allocated by a thread is non-sense. It is memory allocated by the *whole* process (and it is irrelevant which particular thread did the `malloc` library call, or the `mmap` syscall called by `malloc`).